# Request Handling in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am running a simple load test on JMeter (10 users).

After completion I found in summary report that initial request having more that 10 sample and later request are not able to complete desire 10 request.

What should I suppose to do handle this situation.

[image]

Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't contain enough information to state the exact reason of the behaviour, the possible causes could be in:

1. For extra initial requests it might be the case JMeter is appending new results to an existing results file so when you run your script next time you will see i.e. 25 virtual users.
2. For not enough further requests it could be caused by conditional [Logic Controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers) i.e. from [If Controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) or [Switch Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller)
3. Your test execution might be stopped by i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) having `Stop thread on EOF` option set to `True`
4. You simply open wrong results file.

If you need further assistance you will need to update your question with at least 1 screenshot outline of your Test Plan and contents of *jmeter.log* file (normally lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

Comment: Please find enclosed Test Plan

Comment: Actually you should be getting **much more** than 10 requests in total as you're running 10 virtual users for more than 5 minutes. Double check your CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) - it might be the case it is configured to stop threads on EOF so when threads read the CSV file to the end - they are simply being shut down.

Comment: But still not able to find solution why later request count is low..please refer screen shot